# The type Queue is not generic

Tags: java, queue

I have problem with BreadthFirstPath API. When I would like to declare a Queue object in that API, they send me the error "The type Queue is not generic. It cannot be paramterizied.", despite the fact that I am declaring Queue class generic. Does anyone have solution for my problem?

```
public class BreadthFirstPaths {
private boolean[] marked;
private  int[]edgeTo;
private void bfs(Graph G, int s) {
    Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
    q.enqueue(s);
    marked[s] = true;
    while(!q.isEmpty())
    {
        int v = q.dequeue();
        for(int w: G.adj(v)) {
            if(!marked[w]) {
                q.enqueue(w);
                marked[w] = true;
                edgeTo[w] = v;
            }
        }
    }
            }
```

}

```
public class Queue<Item> implements Iterable<Item>{
private Node<Item> first;
private Node<Item> last;
private int n;
private class Node<Item>{
    private Node<Item> next;
    private Item item;
}
public Queue() {
    first = null;
    last = null;
    n = 0;
}
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == null;
}

public void enqueue(Item item) {
    Node<Item> oldlast = last;
    last = new Node<Item>();
    last.item = item;
    last.next = null;
    if(isEmpty()) first = last;
    else oldlast.next = last;
    n++;
}

public Item dequeue() {
    if(isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
    Item item = first.item;
    first = first.next;
    n--;
    if(isEmpty()) last = null;
    return item;
}
@Override
public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: Make sure you're importing the correct `Queue`

Comment: Incidentally, it's conventional to use a single upper case letter for formal type parameters.